# moss 2007 workflows

Tags: sharepoint, moss, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm new to MOSS 2007. I need to create a workflow that looks at a document's review date (a select list predefined to values of 3 , 6 or 12 months) then send an email if the review date has passed.

So the workflow needs to get the documents review date then convert this to date time add to the created date if greater than current date send an email.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible to do using SP designer to create the workflow? I'dd be grateful for any pointers.

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Designer makes it very simple to create these kind of workflows. Have a look at [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101829081033.aspx).

Date manipulation can be a bit of a pain so if you need a little bit more flexibility and have the skills to write a little bit of C# or VB code (Visual Studio not required) then have a look at the [Workflow Power Pack](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/Workflow-Power-Pack-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx). There are plenty of examples on [the associated blog](http://blog.muhimbi.com/search/label/WPP).

Disclaimer, I worked on the WPP so consider me biased (It works great though :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with secondary workflows, that starts, update dates and finish.

Comment: thanks Daniel do you have any examples, or can you explain in a bit more detail?